# Is there a way in spring boot to manually invoke the Exception Advice?

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I have a scenario where is an already existing controller and the service throws exceptions which are handled via the @RestControllerAdvice.
Now i have a new class which i have introduced which invokes methods from the above service class in a batch mode. In my class i have to capture the exceptions or successes bundle them up and return. For any exceptions that occur i need to report the HTTP Status and the error message.
Could you let me know if there is any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own `Exception` class.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    private int errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;

    public MyException(int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

and you can create new `MyException` when occurring any exception and throw it. Then you get this exception in the `@RestControllerAdvice` class.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionAdvice {

    private ErrorCodeMapper errorCodeMapper;

    @Autowired
    public ExceptionAdvice(ErrorCodeMapper errorCodeMapper) {
        this.errorCodeMapper = errorCodeMapper;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = MyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleGenericNotFoundException(MyException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity(errorCodeMapper.getStatusCode(e.getErrorCode()));
    }
}
```

and mapper class like below:

```
@Service
public class ErrorCodeMapper {

    public static Map<Integer,HttpStatus> errorCodeMap = new HashMap<>();
    public ErrorCodeMapper(){
        errorCodeMap.put(100, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        errorCodeMap.put(101,HttpStatus.OK);
        errorCodeMap.put(102,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        errorCodeMap.put(103,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    HttpStatus getStatusCode(int errorCode){
        return errorCodeMap.get(errorCode);
    }
}
```

You can more details to `MyException` and add the error message to the `ResponseEntity`.